# How to use world weather online api

Tags: json, weather, weather-api

hello i was wondering how to use worldweatheronline.com's weather api its request looks something like this...

```
http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=London&format=json&num_of_days=5&show_comments=no&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Im just new to this and really dont know how to use this, any help is appreciated.

Its uses a JSON request and it can be found at here http://developer.worldweatheronline.com/io-docs

The Key xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is been used to hide my key

Comment: In what language do you want to call the API?

Comment: @HAS any that i can preferably i would like to use json and user language of English

Answer (score 1):

This package is designed as a wrapper for the WorldWeatherOnline API:

https://pypi.org/project/WorldWeatherPy/

Answer (score 0):

They have recently published some guides on their blog which show how to use their API in both PHP and NodeJs

PHP [Getting Started with World Weather Online API using PHP](http://blog.worldweatheronline.com/2015/02/05/getting-started-world-weather-online-api-php/)

Node.js [Getting Started with World Weather Online API & Node.js](http://blog.worldweatheronline.com/2015/02/19/getting-started-world-weather-online-api-node-js/)

Answer (score 0):

Here an example 
`http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?key=[API_KEY]&q=48.85,2.35&num_of_days=2&tp=3&format=json`

Here the guide with required and non-required fields :http://www.worldweatheronline.com/api/docs/local-city-town-weather-api.aspx#current_condition_element